# Python Beautiful Soup - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I believe I went through similar posts in detail, but could not find a solution; hence re-posting.
Apologies if the question seems repetitive.

I am trying to scrape job data from LinkedIn as an exercise. I already used the same code on on autonews.com, and it seemed to work perfectly. However, I do not know if this is the way the containers are named on the website, or is it something else in the code that needs to be changed.

Anyway, long story short, for starters, I just need the following info: job title, company name, location and URL. Please see code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101282230&keywords=it%20business%20analyst&location=Germany"

response = requests.request('GET', url)
content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'flex-grow-1 artdeco-entity-lockup__content ember-view'})
job_title = items.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'full-width artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view'})
job_company = items.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__subtitle ember-view'})
job_location = items.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__caption ember-view'})
job_link = items.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'full-width artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view'})

for i in range(0, len(job_title)):
    print(job_title[i].get_text())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
job_title = items.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'disabled.ember-view.job-card-container__link.job-card-list__title'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I have also tried changing containers - going multiple levels up - but the problem seems to persist. Would be immensely grateful if someone would be able to guide here, please and thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugfFq.jpg)

Comment: It's because soup.find() returned None

Comment: Yes, I got that. Was just wondering why it was returning None.

Comment: It's because there is no div element with those attributes. Your GET is only going to return the static HTML and not the dynamic Javascript generated data. You could consider using selenium in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked fine for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101282230&keywords=it%20business%20analyst&location=Germany"

response = requests.request('GET', url)
content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'jobs-search__results-list'})
job_titles = [i.text.strip('\n ') for i in items.find_all('h3', {'class': 'base-search-card__title'})]
job_companies = [i.text.strip('\n ') for i in items.find_all('h4', {'class': 'base-search-card__subtitle'})]
job_locations = [i.text.strip('\n ') for i in items.find_all('span', {'class': 'job-search-card__location'})]
job_links = [i["href"].strip('\n ') for i in items.find_all('a', {'class': 'base-card__full-link'})]
```

Comment: Edit: code works perfect except the link part. I am not able to get the links (URLs). All the other three are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is when you use requests module to get content from web page it gets it at the very first instant it gets a response and it does not wait for relevant content.

If you open the URL in your web browser, you will see LinkedIn shows a loading screen and requests module get that as html or any other first response it gets from the URL. That is why `items` is `null`.

You need to wait for LinkedIn to serve you content you are looking for and then start the scraping.

To do that I recommend you use [selenium module.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selenium-python-tutorial/)

`Selenium` runs its own browser where you can wait for content to load and then start scraping.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Was not aware of this tiny detail on the loading screen. Will have a look at selenium module.